# Two futures together

Tags: grammar

When they will reach, they will see this.

Is this correct? I think it's not. It should be:

When they reach, they will see this.

I've read that after a conjunction we don't use future tense to talk about future if that clause is followed by another future.

Comment: The sentence needs to say what place 'they' will have reached to be idiomatic. 'When they reach the house they will find that he has arrived before them.'

Comment: No, this is not correct. Without saying a place, the reader assumes that they are reaching out -- stretching.

Comment: @ FeliniusRexThank you. BTW, my question is about tenses. Is the tense used in the subordinate clause correct?

Answer (score 0):

Without more context I can't suggest an alternative wording, but no, this is not correct.

> When they get here, they will see this

This is probably what you wanted.

"When they reach, they will see this" sounds rather awkward, but again, without more context, I won't know what exactly you mean.

Comment: my question is about tenses. Is the tense used in the subordinate clause correct?

Comment: It is likely that 'When they will reach' is a subordinate objective clause in a non-standard complex sentence of a colloquial utterence or professional jargon. Its standard syntax may look such: 'I know when they will reach this, and when they will see this.' The pronoun 'this' in the sentence can refer to an abstract situation. For example, 'Bonds have a time period (that is that) when they will reach full maturity, (which has the) meaning (of that) they will reach the actual amount the bond represents.'

Answer (score 0):

That's right. The modal expression *will arrive* is often used to convey future meaning, but is not always required for that purpose, and in particular is unusual in that context, as you say.

(I have replaced *reach*, which requires an object, with *arrive*, which doesn't).